# How to fix "ReferenceError: require is not defined" in vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a vuejs + firebase project and i was trying to import firestore but when i access my page, this is displayed into the console: ReferenceError: require is not defined

I'v tried to put the import section in mounted() but it says my that i need to put the import stuffs in the top, that's what i did

This is below my html (register.html) body:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCNYH-sKZZXZhZt5LxQSDqwet7OTo5KgHM",
    authDomain: "thelogoagency-3a11d.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://thelogoagency-3a11d.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "thelogoagency-3a11d",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "101296201242",
    appId: "1:101296201242:web:00d0e7e3554b518d"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="register.js"></script>
```

The top of my register.js

```
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    data: {
        burgerClass: "navbar-burger",
        menuClass: "navbar-menu",
        mobileMenuIsActive: "",
        mobileMenuHasBeenClicked: false,
        firstNameInput: "",
        lastNameInput: "",
        emailInput: "",
        passwordInput: "",
        authError : "",
        emailErrorClass : "",
        emailErrorHelp : "",
        passwordErrorClass : "",
        passwordErrorHelp : "",
        inputClass: "input ",
        nameErrorHelp: "",
        isLoading: false,
        firebase: firebase,
        db: null,
        numberOfInit: 0
    },
```

And mounted()

```
        if(this.numberOfInit = 0)
            firebase.initializeApp({
                apiKey: 'AIzaSyCNYH-sKZZXZhZt5LxQSDqwet7OTo5KgHM',
                authDomain: 'thelogoagency.tk',
                projectId: '1:101296201242:web:00d0e7e3554b518d'
            });

            this.db = firebase.firestore();
            this.numberOfInit ++
            this.db.collection("users").add({
                first: "Ada",
                last: "Lovelace",
                born: 1815
            })
            .then(function(docRef) {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });

    }
```

It should normaly just work fine because it copied it from firebase's doc.
I know i'm probably doing it all wrong :) Thank for helping

Comment: You can't use `require("firebase/firestore");` from browser, you need to use bundler (I'm not sure about ESM - JS modules). If you will use bundler like webpack it will replace your require with source code for the library. if you have it in script tag you can remove it, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Javascript and not NodeJS, you just must link your lib with

```js
<script src="https://my/lib.js"></script>
```

So you can remove your `require` line :)

Answer (score 1):

Require notation is only used when you are using npm and compiling the JS code. I think that you intend to only use the CDN script tag so you can remove the require line.

Answer (score 0):

Install firebase-admin & firebase on npm , and then try this one "require('firebase-admin')" instead of require("firebase/firestore"); , and a note for you, it is impossible to run Backend Service in Client Side

Comment: But, I thought it was the goal of firebase

Comment: and btw I don't want to use Node

Answer (score 0):

The way i fixed it was, i just removed these two lines!

```
        const firebase = require("firebase");
        require("firebase/firestore");
```

not needed if you are using javascript, and not NodeJS.

> you only need these cdns

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

and to start to firestore:

```
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var db = firebase.firestore();
```